# Using FastMM4 and Indy 10

Tags: delphi, indy10

This has to do with `IndyRegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()` function and FastMM4.

In `IdCompilerDefines.inc` in the `System` folder, I define `USE_FASTMM4`, the compiler errors for `IdGlobal.pas` are as follows:

```
[Error]IdGlobal.pas[2203] Declaration of 'GetBytes' defers from declaration in interface 'IIdTextEncoding' 
[Error]IdGlobal.pas[2203] Declaration of 'GetCharCount' defers from declaration in interface 'IIdTextEncoding'
[Error]IdGlobal.pas[2203] Declaration of 'GetChars' defers from declaration in interface 'IIdTextEncoding'
```

and so on.

If I don't define `USE_FASTMM4`, then it tells me that FastMM4 is not defined in this line:

```
Result := FastMM4.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(AAddress);
```

Comment: You probably need to be very specific about the version of Indy that you are using. Did you take the latest version from the repo?

Answer (score 4):

First, if you make a change to `IdCompilerDefines.inc`, you have to make the same change in all three copies of `IdCompilerDefines.inc` - in the `System`, `Core` and `Protocols` folders (the reason there are three copies is related to a technical issue in earlier versions of FreePascal that prevented Indy from sharing a single `IdCompilerDefines.inc` across its various packages).

Second, FastMM4 was incorporated into the RTL in Delphi 2006, which is the same version that introduced the `System.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()` function.  You should not be defining `USE_FASTMM4` in 2006 and later versions.  Let Indy use `System.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()` so it can delegate to whatever memory manager is actually being used at runtime.  In earlier versions, you can install the full version of FastMM4 and recompile Indy to use it by defining `USE_FASTMM4`.  Even then, you should not be get an error on the `FastMM4.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()` line when `USE_FASTMM4` is not defined, because that line is only compiled when `USE_FASTMM4` is defined.

Third, none of the error messages you have show are related to FastMM4 or the `USE_FASTMM4` define in any way.  The fact that `IIdTextEncoding` is mentioned tells me that you are using Indy 10.6.0 SVN revision 4990 or later (the current SVN revision at the time of this writing is 5302), but there have not been any FastMM-related changes since before that release.  So something else has to be going on to cause those errors, unrelated to FastMM4.

Always make sure you are using the absolute latest revision before reporting problems.  If there is a bug in the latest revision, it can be fixed.  If there is a bug in an earlier revision, it may have already been fixed in a later revision.

Comment: Thanks Remy.  I am using Indy10_5031.  I will check out your suggestions.